# Magento WordPress full integration

Tags: wordpress, magento

I'm trying to FULLY integrate a WordPress site within a Magento site. Not something like the Fishpig extension where it's just Blog functionality. I would need full control as in creating custom post types and running plugins, etc.

I'm trying to replicate this:
http://www.chobani.com/culture/recipes/

The recipes section is run using WordPress, but the rest of the site isn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match the design of Magento with WordPress so they appear seamless?

Comment: I would also need the WordPress backend for the client to use, so it would need to look seamless and be seamless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WordPress Integration extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-1.html):

> FishPig's Magento WordPress Integration is an extension for Magento eCommerce that integrates your WordPress blog with your Magento store. The extension is compatible with Magento Enterprise, Magento Professional and Magento Community Edition.